# my google maps didn't show up

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

this is my code

```
if($_POST){

// get latitude, longitude and formatted address
$data_arr = geocode($_POST['address']);

// if able to geocode the address
if($data_arr){

    $latitude = $data_arr[0];
    $longitude = $data_arr[1];
    $formatted_address = $data_arr[2];

    ?>

    <!-- google map will be shown here -->
    <div id="gmap_canvas">Loading map...</div>
    <div id='map-label'>Map shows approximate location.</div>

    <!-- JavaScript to show google map -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAzAHc75U_oTsrxTjA6oNmpZFMqTXIQgCk"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init_map() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas"), myOptions);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latitude; ?>, <?php echo $longitude; ?>)
            });
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<?php echo $formatted_address; ?>"
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
    </script>

    <?php

    // if unable to geocode the address
}else{
    echo "No map found.";
}
}
?>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type='text' name='address' placeholder='Enter any address here' />
<input type='submit' value='Geocode!' />
</form>

<?php
// function to geocode address, it will return false if unable to geocode     address
function geocode($address){

// url encode the address
$address = urlencode($address);

// google map geocode api url
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&key=AIzaSyAzAHc75U_oTsrxTjA6oNmpZFMqTXIQgCk";

// get the json response
$resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

// decode the json
$resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

// response status will be 'OK', if able to geocode given address
if($resp['status']=='OK'){

    // get the important data
    $lati = isset($resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']) ? $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'] : "";
    $longi = isset($resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']) ? $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'] : "";
    $formatted_address = isset($resp['results'][0]['formatted_address']) ? $resp['results'][0]['formatted_address'] : "";

    // verify if data is complete
    if($lati && $longi && $formatted_address){

        // put the data in the array
        $data_arr = array();

        array_push(
            $data_arr,
            $lati,
            $longi,
            $formatted_address
        );

        return $data_arr;

    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

else{
    echo "<strong>ERROR: {$resp['status']}</strong>";
    return false;
}
}
```

live demo is in http://econmarket.000webhostapp.com/tracking.php it only shows loading map and Map shows approximate location. I read some article and it says that i need to put sensor but idk where to put, maybe if i put sensor=true it will goes work. Do i need to add or remove something?

Comment: I checked your page, there is no javascript there and the function init_map() did not exist. I think you should review all your code

Comment: @WernerWaage it will shown after you find something in geocode

Comment: You should separate the initialization of the map from showing data. You can use javascript functions to dynamically change/update the map if you find an approximate location or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map doesn't have a height.

CSS:

```
#gmap_canvas {
   height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: oh god u save me thanks a lot! i forgot something's stupid

Comment: No problem, we've all been there ;-)